# AspNetCore namespace doesnt exist

Tags: asp.net-core, project.json

I'm following [this course](https://mva.microsoft.com/en-US/training-courses/introduction-to-asp-net-core-1-0-16841?l=JWZaodE6C_5706218965) to learn ASP.NET Core.

I did exactly as they did, I can type `dotnet new` and `dotnet restore`.
I also installed the dotnetcore 1.0.1 SDK preview.

All seems fine, and I should be able to type

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
```

But the only things recognized after Microsoft are cSharp, visualbasic and win32?

Here is my `project.json` file:

```
 {
   "version": "1.0.0-*",
   "buildOptions": {
   "debugType": "portable",
   "emitEntryPoint": true
  },
  "dependencies": {},
  "frameworks": {
   "netcoreapp1.0": {
    "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "type": "platform",
      "version": "1.0.1"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi": "5.2.3",
    "Microsoft." **<< i cannt type AspNetCore here**
    },
   "imports": "dnxcore50"
   }
 }
```

There is no Microsoft."AspNetCore". The only things I do have starting with Asp are:

- AspNet.Identity.Owin
- AspNet.Mvc
- AspNet.Providers.Core
- AspNet.Razor
- AspNet.SignalR
- AspNet.Web.Optimization
- AspNet.WebApi
- AspNet.WebApi.Clients
- AspNet.WebApi.Core
- AspNet.WebApi.Cors
- AspNet.WebPages

Comment: Which IDE or Editor you are using?

Comment: i'm using visualstudio code (as in the coarse) at the moment but same thing happens when i load the json as a project file in vs2015

Comment: Type `"Microsoft.AspNetCore` and press CTRL+spacebar and check

Comment: it eventually worked, i think the problem is because its so new, it wasnt recognized when editing the json file when i typed but after giving the :"" for version selection, it did came up with the version. the code completion wasnt woking, not entirely sure how it got fixed, but for the record i had the machine reinstall aspnetcore sdk and restarted the machine

Answer (score 2):

The code completion doesn't always work when editing the `project.json` file, especially if you're using a lighter editor like VS Code. (Sometimes it doesn't work even in full-blown Visual Studio).

If this happens, don't worry! You can still install any packages you need. Find packages by searching on [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/) and then edit the `dependencies` section like this:

```
"PackageName": "1.0.0"   # Version from package details on NuGet
```

Then, use the `dotnet restore` command within the project directory to pull down all the packages in `project.json`.